# \r\n being added to textfield result in PHP/HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a text area in a form  that does this:

```
<textarea rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
```

In PHP, when form is submitted, this happens:

```
 $text_form = $database -> escape_value($_POST['message']);
```

Then it is sent as part of an email message using PHPMailer:

```
$message .= '<p style="font-family: Arial, verdana, sans-serif;"><strong>Brief Message</strong>: ' . $text_form . '</p>';
```

Last here, is my database method referred to above:

```
public function escape_value($value) {
    if ( $this->real_escape_string_exisits ) {
    if ( $this->magic_quotes_active ) { $value = stripslashes( $value ); }
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    } else {
        if (!$this->magic_quotes_active ) { $value = addslashes( $value ); }
    }
    return $value;      
}
```

This above method is virtually copied from a Lynda.com tutorial, line by line.

Now on the email, if the user hits return in the text field, he gets this

Here is line one.  Now I will press return here.\r\nThis is the new line

Why is there a \r\n being added?  I understand what those mean, but why do they show up?

Comment: Can you show how you invoke PHP Mailer?  Some mail scripts ask you to set the carriage return values when they are invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

> mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

So your string now contains two backslashes and two more letters instead of the newline.

Now the question is what you do with `$value` later. If you insert it into an SQL statement, that's how it should be; if you use it for the mail directly, it has literal `\r\n` instead of carriage return line feed.

Comment: Well I'm not using that var with a database... So just sanitize it differently seems to be the answer. Thanks!